# Error while generating dynamic URL: The reference to entity "retURL" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```html
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}" fields="CaseNumber" />
{!v.simpleRecord.CaseNumber}
{!v.recordId}
<center>
    <lightning:button label="Attach file">
        <a href="{!'/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid='+{!v.recordId}+'/parentname='+{!v.simpleRecord.CaseNumber}+'/'+'&retURL=%2F'+{!v.recordId}}" target="_blank">Attach file</a>
    </lightning:button>
</center>
```

> Failed to save CustomAttachmentRelatedList.cmp: c:CustomAttachmentRelatedList:17,118: ParseError at [row,col]:[18,118] Message: The reference to entity "retURL" must end with the ';' delimiter.: Source

I'm getting the above error not sure what is wrong in my URL.

My Expected URL looks like:

> https://garvitasb2bsc--4hdev.cs60.my.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=5003C000003bdmt&parentname=0114054744&retURL=%2F5003C000003bdmtQAA where ‘500..’ is case id, ‘001’ is the case number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest the merge fields. URL must be generated inside the single merge field `{!}`, and inside you can concatenate the variables and string. Following would be the psuedo code and the query parameters must be separated by ampersand sign (`&`):

```
{!'/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=' + v.recordId + 
    '&amp;parentname=' + v.simpleRecord.CaseNumber + 
    '&amp;retURL=%2F'+ v.recordId }
```

Note the ampersand (`&`) is probably [reserved character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), replace that with `&amp;`.

Comment: still i'm getting this error    'Failed to save CustomAttachmentRelatedList.cmp: c:CustomAttachmentRelatedList:17,75: ParseError at [row,col]:[18,75] Message: The reference to entity "parentname" must end with the ';' delimiter.: Source' @Raul

Comment: The compiler complains about use of ampersand (`&`) in string, replace it with `&amp;`, edited the answer to reflect the same

Comment: thanks! working